# Как узнать длину динамического или неопределенного массива типа char

Tags: c++

Много всего перерыл в интернете, но толкового ответа не нашлось.

Знаю что есть `sizeof()`, который узнает длину статического массива в байтах, но с динамикой это не подходит.

Кто знает, подскажите.

Например, в этом коде:

```
char a[] = "";
std::cin >> getline(a, тут_надо_размер);
std::cout << a;
```

Получается несостыковка: размер мы не знаем, но если я введу фразу "Hello World", как узнать на этапе обработки сколько мне нужно байт?

Comment: Это ужасно, когда пытаются писать на языке без его малейшего понимания. Прочтите K&R для начала, а потом уже программируйте. Без обид.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А не будет оно работать. Так по стандарту. Нужен размер - сохраняйте в отдельной переменной размер. В случае обычных строк в самый конец добавляют ноль, поэтому функции вида strlen и могут получить размер, сканируя строку на наличние нужного символа.

В целом, есть всякие обходные пути "доставания размера", но они сильно зависят от конкретной версии компилятора и даже его настроек. Обычно ими пользуются отладчики.

Пример, который Вы привели, обычно пишут так

```
#define SIZE 250
std::char a[SIZE];
std::cin.getline(a, SIZE);
std::cout << a;
```

Но в С++ эту проблему решили - там есть класс std::vector. Используйте его там, где хотите "динамические массивы".

Comment: я понимаю что #define то деректива, но можно подробнее про эту строчку, мало что знаю, спасибо

Comment: #define - это просто подстановка препроцессора, в данном случае это простой способ задать константу. Можно писать по плюсовому - const int SIZE = 250;

Comment: по плюсовому? это как?

Comment: "по плюсовому" == "на с++"

Answer (score 2):

Если вы инициализируете так `char a[] = "test";`
то размер массива можно определить так:

```
sizeof(a)
```

если же так:

```
char *a = "test";
```

то у вас по сути нет массива, а всего лишь указатель на строковую константу.

Answer (score 1):

На C++ вы должны пользоваться идиоматичными строками (`std::string`), в них описанных вами проблем не возникает:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

Просто, правда?

Answer (score 0):

1. sizeof() он не в байтах, а в char'ах
2. если используешь потоки стандартной библиотеки, то используй и контейнеры из нее же, нет смысла скрещивать ужа с ежом, читай сразу в std::string, а не в массив в стиле С.
3. лучше почитать какую-нибудь книгу по С++, например Страуструпа, сразу отпадет масса вопросов :)

Comment: `char` всегда равен одному байту (кол-во бит может быть разным).

Comment: Думаешь это как-то может помешать sizeof() возвращать размер в char? :)

Comment: Списки следует нумеровать с помощью "N.", тогда они корректно форматируются. Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с форматированием сообщений, информация не просто так отображается справа от поля для редактирования сообщения. :)